# Can you use a Razor Page for a layout in a cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, blazor, razor-pages

I am trying to use a default layout for each cshtml page, but the default layout i want to use is a .Razor file. Can a .razor file be used as a layout for a cshtml?

Comment: Why did you tag this question with blazor ?

Comment: I think @aguafrommars comment is due to what appears to be confusion of terms in your question. **Razor Pages** are an [ASP.NET Core page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) with a `.cshtml` extensions. However you mention `.razor` file - these are **Razor Components** - see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1) . The answer is no - Razor Pages can't use a `.razor` template, but they can use a `.cshtml` template

Comment: @Quango, nope, this question was tagged with blazor, I received the email alert throught my blazor feed. But that's not seems to be related to Blazor, so I asked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add Razor Page Component in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75494366/add-razor-page-component-in-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

**Please edit your question / clarify what you are attempting to do**

**I am going to assume** you are building an ASP.NET MVC C# app using Razor format, ***instead of*** an ASP.NET Core Blazor app, which utilize component files that have the .Razor extension (likely where the initial confusion came from).

If you are asking:

1. ***How to set up a default page layout***

   - then provided you set up your MVC project appropriately, there should already be a partial view that was created by default called  "_Layout.cshtml" in your /Views/Shared/ folder.
2. ***How to ensure that your views utilize your layout page***

   - Then provided the beginning of all of your views utilize what is displayed below, then you should be fine:

At the start of your view pages:

```
@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Tab Title name";
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```