# Add Razor Page Component in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, razor-components

I've added Razor Page Component to my existing MVC application

**Pages/Test.razor**

```
@page "/test"

<h1>Hello World!</h1>

@code {
    
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
});

app.Run();
```

**Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - MVCApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/MVCApp.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <base href="/"/>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
...
```

but it doesn't work: I get 404 on /test

[image]

What am I missing to make Razor Component's routing work with MVC routing?

Comment: Did you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56241125/adding-server-side-blazor-to-an-existing-mvc-core-app)?

Comment: Yes. I can render components, e.g. `@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Counter>())`, but the component is not rendered by routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components` package and add the `_Host.cshtml`, `App.razor`, `_Imports.razor` files to your MVC project.

_Imports.razor:

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Virtualization
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using Project
```

_Host.cshtml:

```
@page "/"
@namespace Project.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

App.razor:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView>
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

Your Endpoints:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
});
```

Test Result:

[image]

If you want to use the UI in Blazor, you can also copy `MainLayout.razor` from a Blazor App and use it in `App.razor` like this:

```
//...
<RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
//...
<LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
//...
```

Note that if you do this, your default page will be a Razor Component with `@page "/"` defined instead of `Index.cshtml`.